# Desabilitar/esconder menu principal

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Soy nuevo en **asp.net mvc**, estoy tratando de hacer mi menu solo visible para los usuarios que han hecho login e invisible para los visitadores o no registrados, no tengo idea de como hacerlo, el menu lo cree usando asp.net mvc 5 web app.

**Este es mi view _Layout:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My fitness web application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Fitness Web App", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Fitness Goals", "Index", "FitnessGoals")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Measurements", "Index", "Measurements")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Routine", "Index", "Routines")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />

    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Logre esconder el menu usando:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre hacerlo usando:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Fitness Goals", "Index", "FitnessGoals")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Measurements", "Index", "Measurements")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Routine", "Index", "Routines")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                }
```